# Fading my page when Loader appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, html

I am creating a filtering mechanism for my content and have this setup, that whenever a filter option is cliked, a loader appears in the middle of the screen before the results are sorted and displayed through JQuery.

What I am hoping to do is to fade my whole page when loader appears on the screen. This is to give an illusion that whole page is at the back while the content is loading.

### The CSS of my loader is:-

```
.ajax-progress {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;     
 }

 .ajax-progress div.throbber {
      line-height: 58px;
      text-indent: 100px;
      word-spacing: 20px;
      letter-spacing: 12px;
      font-size: 45px;
      font-weight: 600;
      font-family: spinjs !important;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #3182c5;

      width: 100px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Whenever a filtering option is selected, the fader appears in the middle of the page for one second and goes away as soon as the results are shown through Ajax. No Page loading takes place.

I am working in Drupal but I guess that's not the point of interest here. I actually don't know what other information is needed for me to aid you in proposing a solution.

Please feel free to ask me

Comment: You could try adding opacity to the main wrapper when the loader is shown and remove it when it's over with jquery (hard to suggest how to do that without full code). Or if you want a dark fade you could add a cover div which is behind the loader div that fills the whole screen and is again shown when the loader is shown and hidden when the loader is hidden and would have a background color like `rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.4)`

Comment: An extremely rough example of the second suggestion I made [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/yV3Ny/1/) (sorry about in formatted code I'm I my phone so there's no tab and the tidyUp button doesn't work on mobile for some reason)

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Since your doing an Ajax request why not utilize its callback functions - `beforeSend` and `success`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: '',
    url: url,
    data: $('filter_form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        /* blanket the whole page and show the loader, 
           see @Last1Here jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yV3Ny/1/
        */
        $('.cover').fadeIn();
    },
    success: function(){
        $('.cover').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Or with the global ajax event handler methods, making it your default loading indicator on every Ajax request.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
    $('.cover').fadeIn();
});
 $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    $('.cover').fadeOut();
});
```

Cheers!